# Hamming Distance Comparison On Large Dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with a large dataset of 64bit hashes. The collection is currently 1.4 million and growing by 50k a day.

I need to continually check new hashes against all hashes in the dataset and find matches within a specific hamming distance as fast as possible.

I'm currently building the data into a VP Tree and searching it.

I'm using this library this library: https://pypi.org/project/vptree/

It takes about 10 minutes to build the tree over 3 minutes to search it.  That's getting longer daily.

I would like to be able to keep up with the incoming volume.  However, right now I'm using 36 cores that are at my disposal and it's not close.

I'm hoping to get suggestions on better ways to approach this. Tools that I don't know about, different algorithms, ect.  Working with datasets this size is new to me.

Any help that can be offered would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution in case anyone else goes down this same road.


The answer is a library called Annoy made by the folks at Spotify.

https://github.com/spotify/annoy

Prior I took 6+ hours to check 1000 hashes.  Using this library I'm able to check 1000 in less than 3 minutes with extremely good accuracy. That's in a single process. Safe to safe this completely solves my issue.